# Service is not ignored even if it has missing dependency

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

I have a service definition, which is something like this:

```
app.logging.event_subscriber.my_subscriber:
    class: AppBundle\Event\Subscriber\MySubscriber
    arguments:
        - '@?app.logging.optional_dependency'
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

My service "app.logging.event_subscriber.my_subscriber" should not be defined if "app.logging.optional_dependency" service is missing, but I get an exception:

```
TypeError: Argument 1 passed to AppBundle\Event\Subscriber\MySubscriber::__construct() must be an instance of AppBundle\Logging\OptionalDependency, null given, called in /app/app/cache/test/appTestProjectContainer.php on line 936
```

Comment: You seem to misunderstanding something. If `app.logging.optional_dependency` is missing, your `app.logging.event_subscriber.my_subscriber` will still be defined, however it will pass `null` for the missing dependency instead.

Comment: @Gerry You are right. I misunderstood the "optional dependency" stuff. I thought, that, if there is a missing dependency in "arguments" section, the service will not be defined at all (as if it was not in services yml).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add default value `null` for argument of your constructor `AppBundle\Event\Subscriber\MySubscriber`

`public function __constructor (OptionalDependency $dependency = null)`

Comment: I misunderstood the "optional dependency" stuff. See my comment under the question. In this case, your proposed solution is the only way, I guess.

Comment: If you need to create a service if only the `app.logging.optional_dependency` exists, there is also a way

Comment: How could I do that? Use compiler pass?

Comment: Yes, that's an option. Or even a bit easier - you may put the declaration of service in a separate file, and then in DIExtension load this file if only declaration of `app.logging.optional_dependency` exists